# Why my R package export imported package's functions?

Tags: r, function, dependencies, package, devtools

I am wondering why my R package is exporting functions that are in the packages on which my package depends.

For example If I

- import ggplot2 into a function in my package like this:

  > #' import ggplot2
  >
  > myfunc <- function(){}
- add ggplot2 into the section Imports (EDITED) of the file DESCRIPTION
- load my package with

  > library(mypackage)

Then I, or any user of my package can do :

> mypackage::ggplot(...)

And I feel like it's useless, it drown my package functions into a lot of informations that I don't need, we'd rather use the ggplot2::ggplot instead of mypackage::ggplot.

Why does is do that ? Is there a way not having this behavior when using my package

Here is the DESCRIPTION file:

```
Package: xxx
Title: xxx
Version: 1.0.38.5
Authors@R: person("xxx", "xxx", email = "xx.xx@xx.xx", role = c("aut", "cre"))
Description: 
Depends: R (>= 3.4.0)
License: GPL-3
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
Imports: 
    DBI,
    rlist,
    ggplot2,
    tictoc,
    RMySQL,
    rjson,
    sodium,
    jsonvalidate,
    jose,
    openssl,
    logging,
    aws.s3,
    R6,
    testthat,
    dplyr,
    stringi,
    desc,
    data.table,
    rstudioapi,
    tryCatchLog
Suggests:
 knitr,
 rmarkdown,

VignetteBuilder: knitr

RoxygenNote: 7.0.2
```

Thank you

Comment: Because you add ggplot2 into the section **Depends**. Add it in the section **Imports**.

Comment: What does your DESCRIPTION file look like?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I meant Imports and not Depends sorry.. as you can see in the DESCRIPTION file i added

Comment: Did you find the answer? I'm also baffled with this in my package. My dependency package is listed in **Imports** (not **Depends**) and I also see functions that i bring in with `@importFrom` appearing as exported by the package

Comment: @Ceres No the question is still open, maybe we should ask the question into a specialized R forum or community